# Two way binding of form input directive with isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am leaning AngularJS, specifically working on learning directives.  Would like to have a form input directive that I can re-use on all my forms to encapsulate all the boiler plate markup. Though I am having trouble getting two way binding to work in my directive.  It is using an isolated scope with its own internal property to store the value of the input field.  I've setup a watch on that internal property that is correctly pushing the value from within the isolate scope up to the controllers scope.  What I am trying to figure out is how to take an initial value from the controllers scope and set it as the initial value in my directive.

Plunker Link: http://embed.plnkr.co/TbVB0q9DHhBCVLQ4U64W/script.js

Typing in the first input box changes the controller scopes property, but not the directives value.  Typing in the second input box changes the directive and the controller property.

I know this is possible using an attribute to pass the initial value. However I am hoping to be able to extract the value from the controller scopes property via the ngModel reference in my directive.

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER:**

For those not sure about why you want to go through the effort of learning directives. Especially when Angular is so powerful even without using directive.  This is one good reason why.

Input fields on my form without directive:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
           <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8" ng-class="{'has-error': userForm.firstName.$invalid}">
               <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="muState.currentUser.firstName" class="form-control" required
                               popover="Cannot be blank" popover-trigger="{{{true: 'mouseenter', false: 'never'}[userForm.firstName.$invalid]}}" />
           </div>
 </div>
```

After using my directive:

```
<ws-form-input input-name="firstName" input-label="First Name" input-placeholder="First Name"
               ng-model="muState.currentUser.firstName"
               required input-error="Cannot be blank"></ws-form-input>
```

Go through the effort. You'll be trading the headaches of learning versus a maintenance nightmare later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify your directive altogether by using the isolated scope's `'='` attribute notation.

Something like this:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
app.directive('inputDirective',function(){  
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {ngModel: '='},
        templateUrl: "directiveTemplate.html",
        require: '^form',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
          scope.form = ctrl;

          scope.required = false;
          // If attribute required exists
          if (attrs.required !== undefined) {                    
              // ng-required takes a boolean which is read from this scope variable
              scope.required = true;
          }
        }
     };
});
```

**HTML DIRECTIVE**

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="directiveInput" 
       ng-model="ngModel" class="form-control" ng-required="required"/>

<br/>
Isolated Scope value of the input box: {{ngModel}}
</div>
```

See [UPDATED PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/BjfyijG7wZsx9CsvByaO?p=preview)

Comment: I could have sworn that I tried this.  However won't be here if I had.  This definitely makes the code in the directive much cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `ngModel.$render`, see ref [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

The following code in your directive will suffice:

```
scope.ngModel.$render = function() {
    scope.inputBinding = scope.ngModel.$viewValue;
};
```

Comment: I did not know about ngModel.$render!  Definitely learnt something about using ngModel inside an isolated scope.